# How to make C# project generate language resx dlls in a separate sub folder of TargetDir?

Tags: c#, wpf, msbuild, localization, msbuild-4.0

We have a C# UI project with bunch of resx files for supported languages. When it is built, the localization support dlls get placed under culture-code\MyTool.resources.dll in the $(TargetDir) of the project. Example is es\MyTool.resources.dll for Spanish.

I am looking for a way to generate these dlls in **$(TargetDir)\langsupport\culture-code\MyTool.resources.dll**. I know how to make the tool look for langsupport at runtime through app config. This question is about csproj magic to change the output path of resource dlls.